# How do I cat or list a guests files in /dev or /proc from the host

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I want to list `/dev/disk/by-path` or cat `/proc` files on a running guest VM from the host.

I found `virt-ls`, `guestfish`, `virt-inspector` and so on, but they all seem to be getting their info from the `dumpxml` or disk images. And `/dev/` and `/proc/` are both mounted virtual filesystems that only exist in memory while the guest is running.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: That looks like "[XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)" question, what is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, I need IP addresses and the device names of disks attached to the VM. (_target dev_ in the xmldump is only a suggestion to the kernel). All of the solutions given online that I could find do not work for me. Being able to read a guests `/proc` would solve this mess for me.

Answer (score 0):

When the Guest OS trusts the hypervisor (somewhat) and is running the Qemu Guest agent you can use that as an inroads to the running guest.

The QEMU Guest Agent Protocol has among others the [`GuestFileOpen`](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-ga-ref.html#index-guest_002dfile_002dopen) and [`GuestFileRead`](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-ga-ref.html#index-GuestFileRead) commands which should allow you to open files on the guest and read their contents.

Comment: The main issue here is that the GA agent has to be running.. Which it is not.. If that is a requirement, I might as well install an agent of myself anyway.